# Access Magento Admin on Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, nginx, magento2

I have a running store on Magento 2 which has multiple websites that I can access in the front end without any problems, for example:

```
https://siteone.mymagestore.com
https://sitetwo.mymagestore.com
https://sitethree.mymagestore.com
.
.
.
```

But when I try to access the admin panel in the same way it redirects me to the main store URL, for example:

https://siteone.mymagestore.com/admin -> Redirects to https://www.mymagestore.com/admin

How can I allow accessing the Magento admin panel on URLs like https://siteone.mymagestore.com/admin as well?

I have tried many aspects to solve the problem but nothing seems to help. Any help on it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong (someone let me know if this is the case) but: you're running Magento through **one** root installation - the others are merely themes of that Magento. It will get redirected because that domain is the **main** domain. That domain controls *all* sites, so you manage everything from only one point. That or... in your db for the subdomains, the site_url,home_url or whatever the fields are are set to the main domain ..

Comment: You are correct, but if the frontend opens for different URLs without any problem, the admin end should also. I know only a single admin panel exist for all the subdomains, but why can't I access it using multiple URLs, similar to the front end.

Comment: The frontend is not the same as the admin panel though, all the frontend does is go to a symlink of an index.php inside a new directory.. index.php is not the file responsible for admin-related stuff, it may work if you symlink everything admin, but then.. when it gets to that point, what's the point of having a multistore instance of Magento2 and just have indiviual set ups>

Comment: When the redirect happens, do you have a trailing slash in the original request?  Is there a trailing slash in the final redirect?

Comment: @cnst No. The slash doesn't matter, even if I add the slash, the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by changing adding the following code in Magento\Framework\Url

getUrl() function - At the end add

Replace:

```
$this->cacheUrl[$cacheKey];
```

With:

```
$finalUrlArray = explode('://', $this->cacheUrl[$cacheKey]);
$finalUrl = $finalUrlArray[0].'siteone.'.$finalUrlArray[1];
return $finalUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible only with Magento at this moment. Magento allows you to specify a custom admin URI (For having your shop on siteX.magestore.com, and the admin on admin.magestore.com for example).

If you need more information, you can check [this issue on magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5033). This is a incorrect behavior on Magento reported two years ago, confirmed on 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and not fixed yet.

As a workaround, on the bug report I've found this:

> This module fixed it for us: METMEER/magento2-multi-store-fix!

You can try to install this module.